# Peewee get count of entries by day

Tags: python, peewee

My Table has a datetimefield, and I'm trying to find the count for all entries grouped by days. So say that I have 3 entries on June 1, 2 on June 2, 10 on June 3, etc.

Then I get the count for it. I realize that it's possible to iterate through all the days from day 1 to the present day, but that looks.. quite frankly, bad. So I'm looking if it's possible to do it without iterating several times.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming sqlite or postgres, I believe the following should work:

```
(Entry
 .select(
     fn.date_trunc('day', Entry.timestamp).alias('day'),
     fn.count(Entry.id).alias('count'))
 .group_by(fn.date_trunc('day', Entry.timestamp)))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate where fn comes form? And also, why are we counting by the id?

Comment: `fn` is a peewee helper. `from peewee import fn`, it exposes a Pythonic API for calling SQL functions. You count the ID because that indicates how many entries existed for a given day.

Comment: Is this answer still working? I'm getting a weird exception when I  use date_trunc inside group_by with the last peewee version (will try to put more info)

Comment: Could be the exception caused because using sqlite with DateTimeField instead of timestamp?

Answer (score -1):

Why not do it in a single pass with collections.Counter()?
EG: http://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html